# Problem with my php webapp + nginx, anyone have ideas?

Tags: php, azure, nginx, azure-web-app-service

I'm new here and I also have some questions about my Azure web app.

I created a webapp with PHP 8.2 with nginx, I'm migrating my website from Windows + Apache to Linux + Nginx.

Currently I have moved my entire website to the new webapp, but I am only able to open my index.php.

Whenever I try to open another page on the website by clicking it redirects me to the nginx 404 page. As if it couldn't find the other pages.

I'll leave below what the nginx configuration file looks like.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to deal with this?

I've already tried changing the nginx file to the php FPM, but in the azure app it seems like it's not installed and I can't install it the same way.

My nginx.conf and default conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 10068;
        multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log off;
        error_log /dev/stderr;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

My default conf:

```
location / {            
    index  index.php index.html index.htm hostingstart.html;
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /html/;
}

# Disable .git directory
location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300; 
    fastcgi_send_timeout           3600; 
    fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
}
```

If needs more information to understand what is happening, let me know, I don't have much idea of ​​how to proceed with this case.

Anyone have ideas?

Try fix my php website.

Comment: We're you using mod_rewrite on apache version of your website?

Comment: Yes, i have a .httaccess on my apache. But i'm not have idea for reply this on nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a try_files directive in your location blocks (`try_files $uri $uri/ =404;`).

Comment: Can you show me an example of configuration ? Thankss for answer.

Comment: Example in the brackets above.